# jQuery Autocomplete widget gets ParseError when calling C# webservice

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, web-services, autocomplete

Trying to get a test bed working for jQuery UI V10 Autocomplete. I have the demo programs working, but when I adapt the code to an example using C# and an ASP.NET webservice, I am getting a status 200 parseerror. The jSon data is coming back wrapped in double quotes. When I put the response in jsonLint, it validates when I remove the outer quotes. It also has the "d." prefix that I expect from an ASP webservice.

How do I get the response to return valid JSON?

jQuery code:

```
$(settings.selector).autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        var data = JSON.stringify({
            prefixText: request.term,
            count: settings.count
        });
        ajaxCall(settings.url, data, {
            onSuccess: function (data) {
                var matches = [];
                $.each(data, function (item) {
                    matches.push({
                        label: data[item].label,
                        value: data[item].value,
                        id: data[item].id
                    });
                });
                response(matches);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: settings.minLength,
    change: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui && ui !== null && ui.item && ui.item !== null) {
            currentValue = ui.item.label;
            if (settings.onChange && settings.onChange !== null) {
                settings.onChange(ui.item, settings.selector, oldValue);
            }
        } else {
            $(settings.selector).val(oldValue);
        }
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        currentValue = ui.item.label;
        if (settings.onSelect && settings.onSelect !== null) {
            settings.onSelect(ui.item, settings.selector, oldValue);
        }
    },
    open: function () {
        $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
    },
    close: function () {
        $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
    }
});
```

WebService Code:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]

[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class TestAutocomplete : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod(BufferResponse = true, Description = "Lookup City")]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string CityList(string prefixText, int count)
    {
        List<AutoSuggestReturn> matches = AssessorBusinessLayer.City.List(prefixText, count);
        Messages.ConsoleLog(string.Format("Prefix: {0} return {1} matches", prefixText, matches.Count));
        string ret = AutoSuggestReturn.ConvertToJson(matches);
        return ret;
    }
}
```

xhr object on return from webservice call:

```
xhr: Object
abort: function ( statusText ) {
always: function () {
complete: function () {
done: function () {
error: function () {
fail: function () {
getAllResponseHeaders: function () {
getResponseHeader: function ( key ) {
overrideMimeType: function ( type ) {
pipe: function ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ ) {
progress: function () {
promise: function ( obj ) {
readyState: 4
responseText: "{"d":"[{\"id\":\"10499\",\"label\":\"Delmar,AL (35551)\",\"value\":\"Delmar,AL (35551)\"},{\"id\":\"2679\",\"label\":\"Delmar,DE (19940)\",\"value\":\"Delmar,DE (19940)\"},{\"id\":\"2401\",\"label\":\"Delmar,IA (52037)\",\"value\":\"Delmar,IA (52037)\"},{\"id\":\"2679\",\"label\":\"Delmar,MD (21875)\",\"value\":\"Delmar,MD (21875)\"},{\"id\":\"3584\",\"label\":\"Delmar,NY (12054)\",\"value\":\"Delmar,NY (12054)\"},{\"id\":\"4780\",\"label\":\"Delmita,TX (78536)\",\"value\":\"Delmita,TX (78536)\"},{\"id\":\"3352\",\"label\":\"Delmont,NJ (08314)\",\"value\":\"Delmont,NJ (08314)\"},{\"id\":\"11550\",\"label\":\"Delmont,PA (15626)\",\"value\":\"Delmont,PA (15626)\"},{\"id\":\"4574\",\"label\":\"Delmont,SD (57330)\",\"value\":\"Delmont,SD (57330)\"}]"}"
setRequestHeader: function ( name, value ) {
state: function () {
status: 200
statusCode: function ( map ) {
statusText: "OK"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `AutoSuggestReturn.ConvertToJson` ?

Auto complete is looking for some type of json array and you should be able to return your `List<AutoSuggestReturn> matches` enumeration without going through a string conversion. Serialization will be handled for you.